# how to open the camera using OpenCV for Android VideoCapture

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am working wiht OpenCV4Android, and I am trying to use VideoCapture class to open the Android Camera and perform further processings on each captured frame.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i'm working on android with opencv and i'm sorry to tell you that you can not open a stream with opencv in cpp. The ndk android dont give any API to access the camera so opencv can not open any stream. I saw one time an API for android 4.4 if i remember well but i did not succeed to open any thing.

Since the realase of android 7.0 you have access to some C function that give you the right to take a picture, check out this header: camera/NdkCameraManager.h.

And if you whant a beginning of code

```
#include <camera/NdkCameraManager.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "gandoulf", __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGW(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "gandoulf", __VA_ARGS__))

void AndroidCamera()
{
ACameraIdList *cameraList; //list of available camera
ACameraManager *cameraManager; // android camera manager
camera_status_t cameraStatus; // enum for the error while using camera


cameraManager = ACameraManager_create(); // instantiate the camera manager
cameraStatus = ACameraManager_getCameraIdList(cameraManager, &cameraList); // get the list of available camera, return enum camera_status_t for the error

if (cameraStatus == ACAMERA_OK) {
    LOGI("cameraList ok\n");
    LOGI("num of camera = %d", cameraList->numCameras);
}
else
    LOGW("ERROR with cameraList\n");
}
```

With that you have the list of camera and you can normaly take a picture with function that you can find in the header.